# nvd3 multibar chart show values

Tags: nvd3.js

I have a stacked multiBarChart created with nvd3: jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/e3kxZ/5/

(1) How can I get each region to display its value near its top?

I tried `showValues(true)` but I don't think that's supported in multiBarChart.

Other concerns I have are:

(2) how to set the text color so that it contrasts enough with the region (dark vs light colors), and

(3) how to keep the text labels from overlapping if any particular region is small.

I found an svg example (doesn't use nvd3) -- it assumes a static size for the chart, but I'd prefer to use something convenient and dynamic like nvd3.

Alternatively, if there is a different js library that supports this out of the box, please let me know and I'll use that instead.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You can add the following option: .staggerLabels(true) to avoid text overlapping

Comment: I've seen an example of that... Does staggerLabels apply to the numerical labels I want to apply to each region? Or only to labels along the axis?

Comment: Could you add your code in a fiddle so someone can have a deeper look and help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion -- http://jsfiddle.net/e3kxZ/5/

Comment: I think this is duplicated from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621208/how-to-display-values-in-stacked-multi-bar-chart-nvd3-graphs/31865794